# Setting up iSCSI on an external hard drive with 4K sector size

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi, advanced-format

I have a WD My Book 3TB external hard drive connected to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I'm trying to make that machine an iSCSI target. Everything is set up, but I can't create a virtual hard disk on that external drive (although I can successfully create it on C). It gives me this error:

```
The virtual disk cannot be created on the selected volume. The parameter is incorrect.
```

I can't create a VHD via Disk Management either. From what I found out, Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't support virtual disks on a 4K sector hard drive (which is what my external drive is). Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: You're trying to expose an external consumer-grade, USB-connected hard drive via iSCSI? That's....a bad idea.

Comment: This is more like an experiment...

Comment: ServerFault is for professional production technologies and environments. Development and Experimental networks, hardware, and technologies are off-topic here.

Comment: What are you using to create your iSCSI extents?

Comment: @MarkHenderson Microsoft iSCSI Target Software 3.3

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - you might have better luck with StarWind products if you're serious about this (not that I recommend doing iSCSI extents on a USB drive) as they don't use VHD's but their own files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a native 4k drive? Run [`Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo x:`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2510009) (where x: represents the drive that you are checking).

If Bytes per Sector *and* Bytes per Physical Sector are the same, then it's a native 4K drive and you're out of luck and will need to move to Server 2012 or later.

Comment: It's a 4K native. I guess there's no way then...